# Check array Key Value in included file in PHP

Tags: php

Please help me to find out the array key value from included file in php.

City.txt has value like:

```
array('mumbai'=>70624,'delhi'=>69514);
```

Main PHP file:

```
$verified_city = include('city.txt');
$city_nm = 'delhi';
if(array_key_exists($city_nm, $verified_city))
{
     echo "Exists";
}
else
{
     echo "Not Exists";
}
```

It is going in else part.

Comment: In `$verified_city` is string (`'array(...)'`), not array. Why you include txt instead of PHP file?

Comment: @Leena Verma Including a text file and then trying to take the data in it as variable doesn't make sense. You should -
1.Save the data in city.txt as json.
2. Parse the data and then use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your city.tx should be a city.php in which you do

```
<?php
   $verified_city = array('mumbai'=>70624,'delhi'=>69514);
?>
```

(and in the main.file you simply `include('city.php');`
or alternatively it could be a .CSV which you read and assign to `$verified_city`.

Comment: @ MBaas : Thank you so much. It works and i have posted first time in Stackoverflow.com and got the answer so quickly. Happy :)

Comment: Great, I'm glad it helped :) Please do not forget to mark as "accepted answer", so that I have some joy, too ;)